# SSRS Putting field from executed Dataset as Parameter to Second Dataset

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, field

My issue is when executing a stored procedure in a DataSet (exec pStoredProcedure) and SSRS populates different Fields for me to use. I wish to make an additional query to one of these fields.
DataSet 1 is:

```
exec pInfos @SessionGUID=@SessionGUID
```

Dataset 2 is simply:

```
select * from myTable where infoHeader is @HeaderInfo
```

In this query, @HeaderInfo is my dataField from the first DataSet that is returned. Note that the tablix is expanding for the number of @HeaderInfo there happens to be.

What's a simple way to put this field in as the parameter and put the result onto a tablix? (note the tablix data source is dataset1).

Comment: Simplest and logical method would be to have the stored procedure return the complete data set that you need.

Comment: @TMNT2014 Unfortunately, I'm not able to modify the stored procedure on the database side. Would there be another way to save the portion of the data set that I need, besides by referencing the data field?

Comment: The first part is pretty simple. You would need to add a multivalued [@] HeaderInfo parameter, set the value from the field of the first dataset and reference it in your second dataset - select * from myTable where infoHeader in (@HeaderInfo). That will get you the two datasets you need. Marrying the two data sets would be the problem. Are you using SSRS 2008 R2 by any chance? The R2 Version had a handy  Lookup function that would easily tie the two datasets together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to TMNT2014 for his comment!

I found two answers to my own question:

The first is to use Lookup, in which I did

```
    select * from myTable
```

I then did a Lookup as:

```
    =Lookup(Field!Headerinfo, Field!infoHeader, Field!ResultValue, "myTable")
```

And the value is as I needed it. I also found that by navigating to parameters and adding your own, you can specify the default Values of that parameter (in parameter settings) and then select the Dataset -> Value Field. Although I didn't test this one, I thought I'd include it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this hard to follow, plus I needed to run my lookup in the group of my first dataset which required more than one lookup field.

First I wasted a ton of time with parameters.  Nothing worked.  Finally, I just added the fields I needed as the lookupset parms to my dataset query;

DataSet1 query:

```
Select a.c1, a.c2, a.c3, rtrim(ltrim(a.4))+'-'+convert(varchar(12), a.5, 101) as LookupKey from myTable a
```

Next I added the same key to my second dataset.

DataSet2 query:

```
Select b.c1, rtrim(ltrim(b.2))+'-'+convert(varchar(12), b3, 101) as LookupKey from myTable b
```

Now my two datasets have equivalent lookup keys based on multiple fields.  Maybe there is an easier way with Lookup and LookupSet, but I didn't see it offhand.

[image: DataSets]

In the Group footer of DataSet 1 I created an expression in the Tablix

```
=Join(LookupSet(fields!LookupKey.Value, Fields!LookupKey.Value, Fields!Comments.Value, "Comments"), vbcrlf)
```

[image: Tablix view]

And giving the following results:
[image: Results]